# Convert ABI to Solidity code

Tags: solidity, abi, parser

Is there a tool to generate a solidity code from the ABI interface?

```
const Ballot = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"delegate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"winningProposal","outputs":[{"name":"winningProposal","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"voter","type":"address"}],"name":"giveRightToVote","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"proposal","type":"uint8"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_numProposals","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]
```

Should result into something like:

```
contract Ballot {
  function Ballot(uint8 _numProposals) {}
  function giveRightToVote(address voter) {}
  function delegate(address to) {}
  function vote(uint8 proposal) {}
  function winningProposal() constant returns (uint8 winningProposal) {}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a tool that takes an ABI and convert it to its Solidity interface: https://bia.is/tools/abi2solidity/

Source code is published on GitHub: https://github.com/maxme/abi2solidity/

Answer (score 1):

grabABI, which is part of QuickBlocks, comes very close. It's open source, so you could modify it slightly to surround its output with the `contract` part and add the squiggles after each function, but it should be easy.

You can find it on github.